¿Cual es el error en mi codigo de Menu lateral en java de Android Studio
En mi código hay un menu lateral y uno inferior, pero al seleccionar una opción del menu lateral no hace nada. Le puse para que te mande a fragments y nop, también lo probe con activities pero nada. Les adjunto mi código a ver si me pueden ayudar
   package com.example.miamanecer;

   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
   import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
   import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
   import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
   import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
   import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
   import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
   import com.example.miamanecer.R;
          
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.Gravity;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.LinearLayout;
   import android.widget.Toast;
 
   import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
   import 
   com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
   import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

   public class Inicio extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


FloatingActionButton fab;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
    replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());


    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    /*fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Inicio.this, Dibujo.class);
            //intent.putExtra("clave", "valor");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });*/

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, 
       drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.oppen_nav, R.string.closs_nav);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_layout, new HomeFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
    }
    //MENU INFERIOR
    bottomNavigationView.setBackground(null);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.nav_home) {
            toolbar.setTitle("Inicio");
            replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.bottom_Perfil) {
            replaceFragment(new PerfilFragment());
            toolbar.setTitle("Perfil");
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

}
//MENU LATERAL
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.nav_home) {//con activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dibujo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_direc) {//con fragment
        replaceFragment(new DirecFragment());
    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_settings) {
        replaceFragment(new ConfiguracionFragment());
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private  void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

}

Este es el código del menu.xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       tools:showIn = "navigation_view">

      <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
           android:id="@+id/nav_home"
           android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home"
           android:title="@string/Inicio"/>

       <item
           android:id="@+id/nav_direc"
          android:icon="@drawable/baseline_psicologo"
          android:title="@string/MPsi"/>

      <item
          android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/baseline_configuracion"
          android:title="@string/MConfiguracion"/>

    </group>
       <item
       android:title="">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_exit"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_salir"
            android:title="@string/MSalir"/>
    </menu>

  </item>

    </menu>

El menú inferior sí abre, pero lamentablemente el lateral no y no sé porque. Y llevo así mucho tiempo, es que al correrlo abre el menu pero al seleccionar una opción no hace nada tan solo cierra el menu y ya. En el código la función de onBackPressed me la tacha
